# How to make phone vibrate in DnD (Do not Disturb) mode

Tags: lenovo, do-not-disturb

Pretty simple question, I have a Lenovo P2 running Android 7. Instead of a phone being entirely quiet I would like it to vibrate for each call/sms/notification. The reason I need DnD to do this because I can schedule DnD to turn on and off whenever I need whereas I need to change silent/vibrate manually and I am prone to forgetting to do this when required. Seems like a pretty basic function so how would I do this? I've already been nearly everywhere in Settings.